# Grails EasyGrid : Adding tooltip to a column header

Tags: jquery-ui, grails, jqgrid, grails-plugin

I have a grails application that uses EasyGrid plugin to display a table.

In one of the pages there's a table that has 3 columns. Now i want to add tooltip to the column headers when the mouse cursor is placed on top of them.

Below is my GSP code to display column headers:

```
<grid:grid name="myTable">
<grid:set col="userName" label="User Name" sWidth="222"/>
<grid:set col="age" label="Age" sWidth="114"/>
<grid:set col="height" label="Height" sWidth="94" bSortable="false"/>
```

Currently the value for the columns are set from the controller. For e.g., for one of the columns the code is like below:

```
age {

                value {user -> user.getAge()}

                enableFilter false

            }
```

I tried adding "title" attribute to the tag and all it does is to replaces the LABEL attribute.

Can you please tell me how to add a tooltip to column header?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need standard tooltips in the column headers you can add `headertitles: true` option to the grid. To set custom tooltips you can use `setLabel` [method](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods).

Comment: I have added that attribute, now where will i put the text to be displayed in that column header?

It now looks like,

`
<grid:set headertitles="true" col="age" label="Age" sWidth="114"/>
`

If i add,


<grid:set headertitles="true" title="This is your age" col="age" label="Age" sWidth="114"/>


Then the LABEL attribute gets affected and the column name becomes "This is your age".

Comment: @donguy76: I have no idea what you do in grails. You've chosen ["jqgrid"](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid/info) as tag of your question. So I suppose you generate JavaScript code which creates jqGrid using your GSP code. Only JavaScript code creates jqGrid. `headertitles: true` is an option if jqGrid which you need use during creating of it. `setLabel` is JavaScript method which you can use too.

Comment: I am using EasyGrid in the Grails application and this seems to be a variant of jqGrid.